# Updating adwords account after change of address / url

Tags: google, google-ads

We've recently changed our url for our site, we've set up 301 redirects from the old pages to the new ones and updated google webmaster tools.

Adwords does not allow you to run ads to one site and then have you redirected to another, is there a way that i cant change the url in adwords to our new url, so that i dont have to setup a new campaign, build up new quality scores ect ect ?

Answer (score 2):

Change the URL displayed in your ads then change each ad's destination URL following this guide http://support.google.com/adwordspolicy/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1310892&rd=1

I don't see any problem with updating the display and destination URL if you've changed domain names. If you have a lot of ad's you may find using the AdWords editor http://www.google.com/intl/en/adwordseditor/ will help make the work more efficient.

Comment: is there a way to do this with out "creating a new ad" as when you try to change it thats what you get. Thus the quality score, ctr ect arnt carried over

Comment: Yes just change your display and destination URLs. You don't have to create new ads.

Comment: Unfortunatly to change those settings you have to click on the little "edit pencil" next to the ad and when you do it gives you this message "Before you edit this ad...
Changing this ad will delete the existing ad and create a new one, which will be submitted for review. The old ad's statistics will still be visible in the total line for deleted ads."

Comment: Seems like that's the case according to http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2404246 and your tooltip. A lot of discussion about this on various websites but there's no getting around it. Export your data for a copy, at least with a new ad and the deleted or Paused ad you can compare data. Maybe create variations of the new ads and compare the data almost like a manual split test so you don't feel too bad about losing the data.